# Finding a joint distribution given a marginal and conditional distribution

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

My question is given a marginal distribution $p_X(x)$ and conditional distribution $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$, am I guaranteed to be able to find a joint distribution $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$. 
In almost every form of this question I have seen asked or discussed, the questions starts given $p_X(x)$ and $p_{Y|X}(y|x)$. I understand in this case, one simply must multiply these two, i.e. $p_{X,Y}(x,y)=p_X(x)\cdot p_{Y|X}(y|x)$.
In my case, I am considering the following
$$p_X(x)=\int_Y p_Y(y)\cdot p_{X|Y}(x|y)dy=\int_Y p_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$$
This in my eyes boils down to, am I guaranteed to be able to find a $p_Y(y)$ that is a valid marginal distribution to give me the above equalities.

Comment: To clarify, you are wondering if it is always possible to find a $p_Y$ that satisfies the left hand equality in your featured equation?

Comment: Correct! If this is something trivial, a brief explanation of why would be useful for me!

Comment: The best I can come up with is that if $p_{X|Y}$ is a valid conditional distribution, there must be an underlying joint distribution (and hence a marginal for $Y$). However, reverse-engineering $p_Y$ may not be easy, and it's not clear to me that $p_Y$ is forced to be unique.

Comment: Existence is all I really care about in this case. Finding a specific example of $p_Y$ or proving uniqueness is not currently the goal for my understanding. As for the underlying joint distribution, would this joint distribution agree both with $p_X$ and $p_{X|Y}$?

Comment: I see, I think what you're getting at is: Do $p_X$ and $p_{X|Y}$ even need to be compatible in the first place?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for my inability to ask my question clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper talks about compatibility of conditional distributions.](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1009213728) In particular, there is a quote in Section 10 that is relevant. I am attaching a picture.

[image: Quote regarding compatibility with the wrong marginal.]

[This other paper that is referenced in the above quote talks about uniqueness of $p_Y$](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226784035_A_characterization_of_a_bivariate_distribution_by_the_marginal_and_the_conditional_distributions_of_the_same_component) in the context that you are considering, but does not seem to address existence.

Comment: Thank you!! This is incredibly close to the answer I am looking for, but you are correct, it is just dancing around the solution I need. I will read a bit further and see what I can find. Thank you for the resources!

Comment: I fear that I am missing some silly additional fact that under some reasonable  circumstances (i.e. strictly positive distribution function) it is easy to construct some appropriate choice of $p_Y$.